# Optional regex groups for comic book titles (python)

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract relevant information from multiple comic book titles with varying content. However, there are only about 5 or 6 different patterns that are followed:

Examples are:

> Green Lantern #21
>
> Green Lantern #21 (Variant Cover Edition)
>
> Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars #4 (of 8)
>
> Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars #4 (of 8) (Variant Cover Edition)
>
> Macabre One Shot
>
> Detective Comics #21 Combo Pack

I want to capture in groups:

1. Title (the only REQUIRED group)
2. Issue Number
3. Total number of issues, e.g. (of 8)
4. All other information, e.g. (Varient Cover Edition) or 'Combo Pack'

I have the beginnings of a regex search string started but am having trouble making things reliably optional,

```
(?P<name>.*?)\s*?(?P<issue_number>#\d*)\s*?(?P<info>.*)
```

It is definitely not complete. Any help anyone could give me would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Can "all other information" be anything, or can you list the possible strings? Think what should come out of `Macabre One Shot Combo Pack`.

Comment: All other information can be anything.

I am not sure whether your example could happen. I guess it is a possibility

Comment: The answer your provided **almost** works. I need 'all other information' to match _anything_. Changing your <other> match to something like .+? messes with the entire regex though...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with optional groups is that the regex engine does not really look for them; it only checks for their presence at the current position where the processing has lead to.

Using `([^#]+)` to capture the title puts the engine at the right position to match the issue number if it's present. If you don't want whitespace at the end of title, use `([^#]*[^#\s])\s*` instead.

```
import re

strings = ['Green Lantern #21', 
    'Green Lantern #21 (Variant Cover Edition)', 
    'Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars #4 (of 8)', 
    'Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars #4 (of 8) (Variant Cover Edition)', 
    'Macabre One Shot', 
    'Detective Comics #21 Combo Pack']

for s in strings:
    print re.match(r'([^#]*[^#\s])\s*(?:#(\d+)\s*)?(?:\(of (\d+)\)\s*)?(.+)?', s).groups()
```

prints

```
('Green Lantern', '21', None, None)
('Green Lantern', '21', None, '(Variant Cover Edition)')
('Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars', '4', '8', None)
('Dejah Thoris & Green Men Of Mars', '4', '8', '(Variant Cover Edition)')
('Macabre One Shot', None, None, None)
('Detective Comics', '21', None, 'Combo Pack')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this regex

```
^(?P<name>.+?)(\s+(?P<issue_number>#\d+))?(\s+(?P<issues>\(of\s*\d+\)))?(\s+(?P<other>\(Variant Cover Edition\)|Combo Pack))?$
```

Explanation

```
^  # beginning of string
(?P<name>.+?)   # Captures the name
(\s+(?P<issue_number>#\d+))?   # captures the issue number optionally
(\s+(?P<issues>\(of\s*\d+\)))?   # captures the number of issues optionally
(\s+(?P<other>\(Variant Cover Edition\)|Combo Pack))?   # captures other info optionally
$ # end of string
```

If your input contains multiple such inputs,you should remove `^`,`$`

Comment: Why `.+?`. Isn't safer to go for `[A-Za-z&]+`?

Comment: @LarsVegas some book names can have characters other than `A-Za-z0-9`..also his input is well defined so it's safe to use it

Comment: Is it possible to reduce the duplicate matches this regex causes?

**EDIT**: I see that when using .groupdict() you can extract just the desired parts

Comment: @TimBueno indeed you can extract relevant data using those names..if this solves your problem,you should upvote-accept the answer

Comment: It helps but I need 'All other information' to match anything. See my comment above...

Thank you for all of the help.

Comment: @TimBueno above regex captures name and issue_number,issues,other optionally..isn't that sufficient!it covers all of your 4 requirements mentioned in your question